# IMPORTXML XPath in Google Sheets table format issue

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the 2nd table from this page into google sheets. I had used `importhtml` but for some reason it does not actually reference the defense tab and just pulls the same table from the offense page. So I decided to try using the XPath method for this. The problem is that the information does not import in the correct format. Instead of a table, each row is imported into a single cell like such:

```
SHORT RIGHT203262.50%1675.2238.10%
```

I used this formula but clearly need help formatting correctly:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://nflsavant.com/game.php? 
team_code=SF&team_id=4500&stype=REG&year=2019&tab=defense", "//* 
[@id='tabDefense']/table[2]/tbody")
```

If there is a way to get the information imported in the form of a table or cleaner that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "http://nflsavant.com/game.php?team_code=SF&team_id=4500&stype=REG&year=2019&tab=defense", 
 "table", 6), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)
```

[image: 0]